# JS — Trying to return AJAX data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs

I've been struggling with getting the data out of an AJAX call using jQuery.  I'm using RequireJS so my JavaScript can be more maintainable/modular.  I've only been using RequireJS for a few days, so I may or may not be doing this right.  Just looking for a way to keep my JS modular and clean.

Here is what I have so far.  I know for a fact that it's getting the correct data because if I `console.log(data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)])`, the data is there.  The JSON file is long so I won't show you that, just take my word for it — it works.

```
var maze;
define(["jquery"], function($){
    $.ajax("js/mazes.json", {
        dataType: "json",
        type: "get",
        success: function(data){
            var maze = data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];
        }
    });
    return {
        randomMaze: maze    
    };
});
```

I also tried this (declaring `maze` within anonymous function)

```
define(["jquery"], function($){
    var maze;
    $.ajax("js/mazes.json", {
        dataType: "json",
        type: "get",
        success: function(data){
            var maze = data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];
        }
    });
    return {
        randomMaze: maze    
    };
});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Just trying to return `data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.ajax()` `success` returns results asynchronously , `maze` may not be defined when called synchronously outside of `success` at

```
return {
        randomMaze: maze    
    };
```

Try returning jQuery promise object `$.ajax()` from function , returning object within asynchronous `success` callback

```
 // return jQuery promise object
 return $.ajax("js/mazes.json", {
        dataType: "json",
        type: "get",
        success: function(data){
            // return object as jQuery promise value
            return {
                     randomMaze: data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];
            }
        }
    });
```

See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)